# Edges of polytope in python

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I have looked all over for this, but I can't find anything! I used [`pycddlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycddlib) to get the vertices of a polytope from the inequalities representation. However, I need not only the vertices, but the edges as well. I can't find any packages to get them; convex hull libraries give facets or vertex lists but not edges.

Comment: If you're on Linux, Mac OS, or FreeBSD, [Polymake](https://polymake.org/doku.php/tutorial/face_lattice_tutorial) can compute the [Hasse Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) of a polytope. Perhaps these lattice structure can give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two vertices constitute an edge if both of them are on two planes.

If library doesn't return information about plane-vertex connectivity, than for each vertex check on which planes it is by putting it in inequalities. Than find pairs of vertices that share two planes.

Comment: Ya, I ended up doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the edges as follows:

```
poly = pcdd.Polyhedron(mat)

# get the adjacent vertices of each vertex
adjacencies = [list(x) for x in poly.get_input_adjacency()]

# store the edges in a matrix (giving the indices of the points)
edges = []
for i,indices in enumerate(adjacencies[:-1]):
    indices = list(filter(lambda x: x>i, indices))
    l = len(indices)
    if l>0:
        col1 = np.full((l, 1), i)
        indices = np.reshape(indices, (l, 1))
        edges.append(np.hstack((col1, indices)))
Edges = np.vstack(tuple(edges))
```